# Camera flashlight project has stopped while clicking

Tags: android

I am working with camera flashlight project.

It load on the emulator but when I click on the "On" button it has stopped unexpectedly. Here is the cat-log https://dl.dropbox.com/u/15065300/logcat1.png

Here is the code:

```
public class FlashLight extends Activity {


    private final static String LOG_TAG = "FlashLight";  
    private Button mOnBtn;   
    private Camera mCamera;    
    private boolean isActive;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

      //this will be inside your onCreate...
        mOnBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.on_btn);
        mOnBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                flipSwitch();
                processClick();

            }
        });
   }

    //these will be outside your onCreate
    public void flipSwitch() {
        isActive = !isActive;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        try{
            mCamera = Camera.open();
            mCamera.startPreview();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Camera is  present", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } catch( Exception e ){
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Impossible d'ouvrir la camera");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        if( mCamera != null ){
            mCamera.release();
            mCamera = null;
        }
        super.onPause();
    }

    public void processClick() {
        if(isActive) {
            Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
            params.set("flash-mode", "torch");
            mCamera.setParameters( params );
            mCamera.startPreview();
        }

        else { 

             Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
             params.set("flash-mode", "off");
             mCamera.setParameters( params );
             mCamera.stopPreview();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: have u tried it as `params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON);
mCamera.setParameters(params);` ?

Comment: Yes, I have tried it first and secondly I am trying this way.

Comment: line number 74 is:  Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a `NullPointerException` on line 74 of `Flashlight.java` in your code.

It's probably that `mCamera`  or `params` is being used while it's value is null. Check the initializations/assignments to these values.

Comment: The line number 74 is: **Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();** Can you elaborate further please?

Comment: @AsimKrishnaDas So the only thing that can be null on that line is mCamera.  Step through your code in the debugger and see why it's null.  In this case, there is only one place where you instantiate mCamera which is mCamera = Camera.open();  Have you added permissions to the manifest?  You should also assume in your code that Camera.open() will fail (another app might be using it).  In fact, you should always assume that any resource outside your app will not be available and check for null then take the appropriate action.

Comment: @Simon If I associate two buttons( one is for on and another is for off) it shows no error but when I associate one button it shows the error! Please [see this how I tried this[(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14444410/changing-two-button-into-a-toggle-button)